# SetFont keeps failing with arguments did not match - Apple OS

Tags: wxpython, wxwidgets

I am developing an app which is a Hex editor for Mac's, but I really need to add a mono-space font when updating the TextCtrl's, which are set as multi line read only controls. There are 3 of them, one shows the offset in Hex, one shows the actual raw bytes, and the third would show the raw text. I have set the foreground colour of the text via

```
self.mainTextArea.SetDefaultStyle(wx.TextAttr(wx.RED))
```

and it works perfectly, but no matter how many times I try to set the font, it errors with:

```
self.mainTextArea.SetFont(wx.Font(11, wx.FONTFAMILY_TELETYPE, wx.FONTSTYLE_NORMAL))
TypeError: Font(): arguments did not match any overloaded call:
overload 1: too many arguments
overload 2: argument 1 has unexpected type 'tuple'
```

and seven more overloaded arguments. I've tried setting the control to StaticText, and using the Label as the text to be updated, RichTextControl, etc, etc, but no matter how I change the Ctrl, any time I set the font, it fails with the error above.

The text control and modifying the font is as follows:

```
        self.mainTextArea = wx.TextCtrl(panel,2, size=(630,650),style=wx.TE_READONLY|wx.VSCROLL|wx.HSCROLL|wx.TE_MULTILINE|
                                    wx.TE_RICH2)
    self.mainTextArea.SetFont(wx.Font(11, wx.FONTFAMILY_TELETYPE, wx.FONTSTYLE_NORMAL))
    self.mainTextArea.SetBackgroundColour((0,0,0))
    self.mainTextArea.SetDefaultStyle(wx.TextAttr(wx.RED))
    vBoxMT.Add(self.mainTextArea, wx.EXPAND)
```

Is it possible to change the font on an Apple OS or what am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: can you show how you setting the font? What is the exact line?

Comment: Igor, see the edited post above - thanks!

Comment: Supply all of the arguments for `font` i.e. `SetFont(wx.Font(11, wx.FONTFAMILY_TELETYPE, wx.FONTSTYLE_NORMAL, font_weight, font_underline, font_name)`. The 3 you are missing can come from the existing font or you can declare them separately.

Comment: I can't mark the above answer as correct as I don't see the checkmark but the answer above led me to solve my issue. The line of code that corrected my problem is `self.mainTextArea.SetFont(wx.Font(13, wx.TELETYPE, wx.NORMAL, wx.NORMAL))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry YYC_CODE, I was in a hurry and just banged in a comment.

Supply all of the arguments for font i.e. SetFont(wx.Font(11, wx.FONTFAMILY_TELETYPE, wx.FONTSTYLE_NORMAL, font_weight, font_underline, font_name). The 3 you are missing can come from the existing font or you can declare them separately.

> A font is an object which determines the appearance of text, primarily when drawing text to a window or device context. A font is determined by the following parameters (not all of them have to be specified, of course):
>
> Point size    This is the standard way of referring to text size.
>
> Family    Supported families are: wx.DEFAULT, wx.DECORATIVE, wx.ROMAN, wx.SCRIPT, wx.SWISS, wx.MODERN. wx.MODERN is a fixed pitch font; the others are either fixed or variable pitch.
>
> Style The value can be wx.NORMAL, wx.SLANT or wx.ITALIC.
>
> Weight    The value can be wx.NORMAL, wx.LIGHT or wx.BOLD.
>
> Underlining   The value can be True or False.
>
> Face name An optional string specifying the actual typeface to be used. If None, a default typeface will chosen based on the family.
>
> Encoding  The font encoding (see wx.FONTENCODING_XXX constants and the Font Encodings for more details)

I think only the last 2/3 are optional

Comment: Thanks! Your little comment helped me solve my issue as shown in my response. I also included the line of code that solved my issues. Such a picky little thing - doesn't like wx.FONTFAMILY_TELETYPE, just wx.TELETYPE. Not sure why considering the autocomplete on my IDE shows to use the entire string with the FONTFAMILY included. Thanks once again!